# how to change dock icon using swift programming language

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, dock

how to change os x app icon in the dock while the program is running using swift?
I have used nsdocktile class but I didn't found any function for changing the icon

Comment: Have you tried the `contentView` property?

Comment: I have tried assigning nsdocktile object contentView property to nsview object but it gave me error while running

Comment: it is not error but the app stops when I press the button that changing dock icon